# Moving VBA function to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado

I have a bit of VBA code running in MS Access and I want to "upsize" it to a stored procedure. It uses ADO now to generate the ranking (PLAATS in dutch) but I have to make this work on a SQL Server. Who can help?

The code in VBA is:

```
Function InvullenUitslag()

    Dim MijnDb As Database
    Dim rsWEDS As Recordset
    Dim iCategorie As Integer
    Dim iPlaats As Integer
    Dim iExequo As Integer
    Dim dblTotaal As Double
    Dim iAantalDeelnemers As Byte

    Set MijnDb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
    Set rsWEDS = MijnDb.OpenRecordset("Q_UITSLAG")

    rsWEDS.MoveFirst

    If Not rsWEDS.EOF Then
        iCategorie = rsWEDS![CATEGORIEID]
        dblTotaal = -1
        iPlaats = 0
        iExequo = 0
        iAantalDeelnemers = 0
    End If

    While Not rsWEDS.EOF()
        If Not (iCategorie = rsWEDS![CATEGORIEID]) Then
            iPlaats = 1
            iExequo = 0
            iAantalDeelnemers = 1
        Else
            If Abs(dblTotaal - rsWEDS![iTOTAAL]) <= 0.0001 Then
                iExequo = iExequo + 1
                iAantalDeelnemers = iAantalDeelnemers + 1
            Else
                iPlaats = iPlaats + iExequo + 1
                iExequo = 0
                iAantalDeelnemers = iAantalDeelnemers + 1
           End If
        End If

        rsWEDS.Edit
        rsWEDS![PLAATS] = iPlaats
        rsWEDS![AANTALDEELNEMERS] = iAantalDeelnemers

        If iExequo > 0 Then
            rsWEDS![EXEQUO] = "*"
        End If

        rsWEDS.Update
        iCategorie = rsWEDS![CATEGORIEID]
        dblTotaal = rsWEDS![iTOTAAL]
        rsWEDS.MoveNext
    Wend

End Function
```

Comment: for starters... is this data in SQL Server? `DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)` usually refers to an Access database, not a SQL Server

Comment: the data was in an Access database and I'm moving it to SQL Server. I'm a starter in this matter

Comment: I guess your first step is to get it into SQL Server. Can you explain what the VBA is doing with data samples? It looks like it might be a partitioning type query. Which version of SQL Server is it going into?

Comment: I use it for ranking results in a gymnastics competition. The table has names and the apparatus results. Based on the total scoring I need to set a ranking.

Comment: I use it for ranking results in a gymnastics competition. The table has names and the apparatus results. Based on the total scoring I need to set a ranking.
The table is like
Name, Level, ResultApparatus1, ResultApparatus2,TotalScore

Example:
Jimm, Level A, 8.0, 9.0, 17.0
Jack, Level A, 7.2, 8.4,  15,6
John, Level B,  8.2, 7.6, 15,6

In the Collumn Plaats I need to set a ranking based on the total in Each Level. It includes a check that when 2 persons have the same total that they get the same rank and the next skips a place, like place 1, place 2, place 2, place 4

Comment: What's the definition of Q_UITSLAG?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a ranking of the participants based on the totalscore and split (partitioned by) Level.

I think you need the RANK() with PARTITION BY clause for this. Your result will look something like this:

```
declare @table table (
     Name nvarchar(50)
    ,[Level] nvarchar(1)
    ,ResultApparatus1 decimal(12,1)
    ,ResultApparatus2 decimal(12,1)
    ,TotalScore decimal(12,1)
)

insert into @table values ('Jimm','A',8.0,9.0,17.0)
insert into @table values ('Jack','A',7.2,8.4,15.6)
insert into @table values ('John','B',8.2,7.6,15.6)
insert into @table values ('Frank','B',8.2,7.6,15.6)
insert into @table values ('Mark','B',8.2,7.8,15.8)

select 
    *
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Level] ORDER BY [Level], TotalScore DESC) Position
from 
    @table
```

This will return the following resultset:

```
Name    Level   ResultApparatus1    ResultApparatus2    TotalScore  Position
Jimm    A       8.0                 9.0                 17.0        1
Jack    A       7.2                 8.4                 15.6        2
Mark    B       8.2                 7.8                 15.8        1
John    B       8.2                 7.6                 15.6        2
Frank   B       8.2                 7.6                 15.6        2
```